# What is a 'floating bus'?

Tags: bus

Recently, the Curiosity rover experienced an internal short in its RTG - which, according [to](http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/politics-and-nation/mars-rover-curiosity-bounces-back-from-electrical-glitch/articleshow/26474534.cms) [a](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/mars-rover-curiosity-bounces-back-from-electrical-glitch/) [bunch](http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?release=2013-340) of sources, was mitigated due to the rover having a 'floating bus' between its wiring and its chassis. When answering [this Space.SE question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2941/what-caused-curiositys-electrical-trouble/2942#2942), I ran accross a problem: I have no idea what a floating bus is.

What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's one that doesn't share grounds between the two systems it is connecting. It does so by using either optical or magnetic links instead of voltage levels to transfer data.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHTHX9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>